# PowerBI: How to create a new table by getting difference of value on a day level

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table imported in PBI which has data similar as shown below

```
    Date       Time         ID          Value
===============================================
01/01/2023   00:00:00      101         10000
01/01/2023   00:00:00      102         150
01/01/2023   12:00:00      101         20000
01/01/2023   12:00:00      102         250
01/01/2023   18:00:00      101         30000
01/01/2023   18:00:00      102         350
02/01/2023   00:00:00      101         40000
02/01/2023   00:00:00      102         450
```

I need to create a new table in PBI which will have the aggregated consolidated value at a date level by ID, something like below

```
    Date        ID          Value
===============================================
01/01/2023     101         30000
01/01/2023     102         300
```

For a date **01/01/2023**, we subtract the next days first value with today's first value to come up with the consolidated value and so on for the remaining values in the table

Is it possible to achieve this in PBI itself.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks